# How To Invoke Method With Specific Parameters In Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods

Here is the sample code,

```
def fun(a = "default", b = "default")
    puts "#{a} and #{b}"
end
fun("hello")
```

Here i want to pass value only for `b` not for `a` (i.e output will be default and hello).

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Ruby >= 2, you might convert it to use [keyword arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) like this:

```
def fun(a: "default", b: "default")
  puts "#{a} and #{b}"
end
fun(b: "hello")
```

This should produce expected output.

Hope that helps!

Good luck!

**UPDATE - `hash` "approach"**

```
 def fun(options = {})
   defaults = { a: "default", b: "default" }
   options = defaults.merge(options)
   puts "#{options[:a]} and #{options[:b]}"
 end
 fun(b: "hello")
```

Comment: What about in ruby < 2. Any other way to solve this.

Comment: For ruby < 2 you might just use a hash, please check answer updated for more details